# How can I find out the device name and the OBEX interfaces from a USB device?

Tags: linux, usb, obex

In a shell-script (or Perl) I need a subroutine that returns for all my  USB devices, their device names, and, if available, their respective OBEX interfaces.
I managed to get the device names and - with `obexftp --usb` - the obex-interfaces.

How can I find out which device belongs to an OBEX interface number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the project site seems to indicate that [you can't](http://dev.zuckschwerdt.org/openobex/ticket/13)